# Setting a function from one object to called by another object in arduino library

Tags: c++, arduino, libraries, led

I'm a little new to writing in C so I hope I'm not to far off base here.

I'm working on a library to handle the control of multiple types of LED ICs.  There are a ton of different types of RGB Pixel libraries each with their own unique naming, but all really perform the same basic actions.  A "strip" or "strand" object is created, each pixel gets a color value set, and the strip then gets updated.

My library handles getting pixel color values from software in the back ground and providing the user with the most recent values from an array belonging to the object.

What I would like is to allow the user to initiate their LED strip object and pass a reference to that object to my library, and then allow them to pass their objects "setPixelColor()" function and "UpdateStrip()" function to the library as well.  If this is achievable then I believe my library could then handle all of light control operations for any given PixelLibrary.

I believe what I'm looking for is the proper way to pass a functions pointer between objects?  Not looking for someone to do this for me, but just looking for directed guidance.  Been searching google for while this morning, but I don't know that I'm even using the proper terms.  Any advice or guidance would be a big help. Thanks!

Comment: [tag:c] or [tag:c++]? Be specific please! And also best show some code you have tried already ...

Comment: Lookup for function pointers, yes. Also lookup for member function pointers, static member function pointers, and what you can evtl. do to pass an object context in c++ (usually done with structs/handles in c).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you need is a base class or virtual base/interface. You define a class with common data and methods which work across all your LEDs. This common or abstract class defines the common functions.  Each of your LED strand types will then inherit the base class/interface and implement the specific functions to set an LED for example.

Using this approach the application code works using the Base class/interface methods treating all the strands the same way.

If you use this approach, I also recommend you create a static factory method which returns a base class/interface pointer after creating the specifically required object.

abstractController=CreateLEDStrandController("Strand Type");//Creates the right object, returns an abstracted base class pointer.

abstractController.SetLEDColor("RED"); //Actually calls the specific object SetLEDColor

Comment: I do not know if the current compiler can leverage the information, but it's good habit, in these cases, to flag the method in the derived classes as final. The keyword will tell the compiler that further derived classes are not allowed to have own implementation of the method.
Incidentally it should also optimize the execution, as it makes superfluous to go through the VMT.